# How to check if browser back is exists?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Am using j query 1.9.1. and i want to find if browser has back icon or not, depend on that i have to show back icon in my html page. I created this page with html5 and media queries for support all browsers. And faced one issue with show back icon.

```
$(document).ready(function (e)
{
   if(window.history.length>1){
     //here i shows back icon
   }
});
```

The above condition is works fine for chrome. And i want to get code for support all browser capability. Any idea to achieve this?

Comment: why would you *want* to? That's the reason browsers **have them built in**. It would go against design conventions?

Comment: this should work on all browsers already, as all support the `window.history` object.

Comment: Really sounds like an XY problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.history.length` should work in a consistent way in all 5 major browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE. I am assuming that back button you want to show is a custom button in your webpage and not the actual browser back button, cuz you should never mess with default browser functionality.

Comment: FYI, this won't work as the window.history.length tells you the length of the history not where you are in the history.  If you click on links to go 2 pages deeper and then hit back twice, the history length will be 3 even though though you are on the original page you started on.